# PuTTY always opens on the left side of the screen

Tags: windows-7, ssh, putty

This is an odd problem, and it's not even a real problem, it's just a minor annoyance. But I open this program many times a day, so it annoys me many times a day.

Every time I open PuTTY, the window opens on the left side of my desktop. Every other program will re-open in the same place it was when it closed. PuTTY always opens on the left (and in a slightly random position, too, which is also odd). I prefer my terminal windows on the right, and I have to open SSH windows 15+ times a day.

I'm on Windows 7. I have no idea if this is a PuTTY issue, a Windows 7 issue, or a combination of the two.

I thought maybe it had to do with how I'm closing the windows (usually by typing "exit" or "logout"). But closing them by clicking the red X has no effect either.

Answer (score 0):

In PuTTY Configuration, load your session profile and go to Window > Behaviour, select 'Save Position and Size on Exit' and save the profile.

Comment: That option is not in my Window->Behavior menu. https://i.imgur.com/MRP0iNP.png

Comment: @felwithe Sorry, I should have checked. I thought it would have been in PuTTY, but it's only in KiTTY http://www.9bis.net/kitty/